# Csv file - User permission needs to be created after each save

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, permissions, csv

For context, I'm uploading a csv file to a Postgres database via the psql command line. The cmd can only access the file after I add `Everyone` to its permissions and allow full control.

The weird thing is that every time I open the csv and resave it, the permission for `Everyone` disappears which means I have to re-add it each time I edit the file. It's time-consuming and annoying, is there any way to set the permission permanently?

Comment: With what application do you open and save the csv?

Comment: I download it from Google Sheets and if it needs editing, open it with Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel deletes the original file and creates a new one in its place. (This way, if the system crashes, you get to keep either the new file *or* the old one – you don't end up with a half-written chunk.)

This results in the new file simply inheriting the default permissions from the parent directory. Although Windows detects this kind of save operation and automatically transfers *some* attributes from the old file to the new one (through "file system tunnelling"), it doesn't preserve file permissions.

(In other words, the permissions are not permanent because the *file* itself is not permanent.)

So you will need to grant inheritable permissions to the parent directory, which will automatically grant them to *all* files in that directory. (If that is a problem – create a dedicated subdirectory *just* for the CSV file, and grant permissions on that.)

It's really unlikely that you actually need to grant permissions to `Everyone`. Only the account actually used by Postgres needs read permissions, which could be `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`, or `NT SERVICE\PostgreSQL`, or something along those lines.